# Create Firebase project dynamically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web application based on node.js and firebase. the database is created using my personal Gmail but I want to create one for each user linking their google account with the application. how to create a firebase project using code and activate the following service for the users.

```
Cloud firestore database
Cloud Function
Storage
```

The objective behind this is that app is free up to a limit. I want each user to take advantage of the firebase blaze plane. so this way the users who came for testing the application will not increase my cost.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have a **very** hard time trying to create and manage a project for each user in a way that meets your needs.  Not only is there no client API for creating a project, there are limits to how many projects can be created using a single Google account that does not require billing.  This is just not a supported situation with Firebase and Google Cloud projects.